# error getting http web response in windows phone app

Tags: windows-phone-7, web, httpresponse, httpserver

I am developing a windows phone app.I am sending parameters[POST] to a server.There is no response from server.I found that the error is "error getting http web response".Why is this problem occuring?
There is a response from server , when I send parameters and check response with the help of "Postman" plugin for chrome .

Answer (score 0):

I use following 2 approaches how to troubleshoot such problems.

1. Set up the debugger so it will break on .NET exceptions. Most likely, you'll stop on a WebException. In the debugger you'll see a lot of exception's properties, containing more information on what has failed and why.
2. Install [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html), capture your Internet-facing NIC, run your app in the simulator, observe your app’s network traffic (type HTTP in filter, press Enter, then right-click on packets and select “Follow TCP stream”). Most likely, you'll see some HTTP error code in the response from your server.

P.S. Postman plugin for chrome / opera's built-in dragonfly / IE's built-in developer tools are rarely useful in such cases. There're too many differences between desktop and mobile browsers. Even worse, many web servers usually send different things to mobile clients.